# Creating new sheet based on the row with new header names

Tags: excel, vba

I have to create new sheet using macros based by naming the first column value (Active cell) and need to give different header names and specific column values need to copy to the newly created sheet.

Note: A few column values need to copy from the source sheet to new sheet and need to give name for new sheet first column values of active cell. It should not apply for all column values, I mean name should be active cell value only.

As per the attached screen shots, I need to create value of project name column we need to create new sheet (second screen shot required output).

[image]

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Showing your code is a great way to start a post on this forum.  Note that StackOverflow is a collaborative site for helping with *specific* coding issues, not a code-for-you service.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should be the goal:

```
Dim lrs as long, lrd as long, i as long
lrs = Sheets("Summary").cells(Sheets("Summary").Rows.Count,1).end(xlup).row
With Sheets("EMDN_SW_Project") 'longer to type than "Summary"
    for i = 2 to lrs 'assumes header in row 1
        'if statement if needed
            lrd = .cells(.rows.count,1).end(xlup).row
            .cells(lrd+1,1).value = Sheets("Summary").cells(i,1).value
        'end if
    next i
End With
```

I would recommend formatting at the end with the desired format, as opposed to assessing the formatting as you go (much slower).

Comment: Above code each time inserting values to newly created sheet which is causing duplication of records.Please help me in this. I am not expert in macros

Comment: Ashok, did you put in your preferred if statement to allow only the desired data to be pulled?  If not, then all data will be pulled over to the new sheet.  Note that I gave you a general type of macro to help you get to where you're trying to be.  You would need to add your own additional information.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe somthing like that can help you. Creating a sheet for evey entries in a specific column of a Table.

```
Private Sub CreateSheets()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim RowCount As Integer
    Dim TempName As String
    Dim ImportTable As ListObject

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("WorkSheetName") 
    Set ImportTable = ws.ListObjects("TableName")

    RowCount = ImportTable.ListRows.Count

    'create a sheet for each value in a specific column of a table
    For i = 1 To RowCount
        TempName = ImportTable.DataBodyRange.Cells(i, ImportTable.ListColumns("ChoosedColumn").Index)
        Sheets.Add.Name = TempName
    Next
End Sub
```